# What does the LCD driver board do?

Tags: lcd

As you know, the LCDs for laptops, tablets, etc. come with a driver board attached to them. I know they drive the backlight whether it's CCFL or LED. But does this board do anything else as well? For example, doing some process on the data, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

It directly drives the state of the pixels on the LCD display. If your video source did that, the connector would need a dozens(?) of pins in the connector. Your video source would also need to manage the pixel refresh.

Comment: I think you'd need well more than dozens; even a simple matrix array would need one per row and one per column, making several thousand on modern resolutions! And I don't think that would be adequate, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not satisfied with the argument! The number of wires of the ribbon cable connecting the LCD driver to the LCD itself is no more than the number of the pins.